# ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, thread-safety

Is it thread safe to create a new instance of `ArrayList` via constructor `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> sourceCollection)` without any additional sychronization, supposing that `sourceCollection` is synchronized? More specifically, can we rely in that case on the new list to contain exactly the elements that were in the collection at the time `new ArrayList(sourceCollection)` was invoked?  And can we rely on the new list to be in a consistent state?

I'm asking this question because I've seen examples in books on concurrency of how to confine objects to local variables on a thread's stack. In these examples a method is passed a reference to a shared object, and inside the method a copy of the object is stored in a local variable -- all this without any synchronization. It is claimed that thread safety can be achieved in this way. A general example would be:

```
public void someMethod(Collection<String> source) {
    List<String> localList = new ArrayList<>(source);
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's only safe if the source is safe (e.g., immutable, synchronized or concurrent).

Comment: Do you mean even if `sourceCollection` is *un*synchronized?

Comment: No, I mean synchronized.

Comment: If you are passed in a Collection source, you *have* to assume that it's safe to read it and iterate it. Otherwise ... what can you do with it? It is really the caller's job to make sure that, at least within the method invocation, the collection has a stable, consistent view. Then you don't need a method-local copy.

Comment: It's just that one of the definitions of thread safety and one that is used in Java Concurrency in Practice is that a class is thread safe if it can be used without the client of the class taking any additional precautions to ensure the proper behaviour of the class in a multithreaded environment.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: as @John Bollinger justly mentioned, particular `ArrayList` implementation is not covered by language specification. So written below is true for Oracle java 8 implementation.

---

Yes, it is safe if `source` is synchronised collection, because `ArrayList` constructor in this case uses `toArray()` method of source collection, which is synchronised as well and produce new copy of data:

```
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    elementData = c.toArray();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In a sense.  But the `ArrayList` constructor in question is not *documented* to behave that way, and its documented behavior is consistent with alternative implementations that would not be thread-safe.  In this sense, no, the proposed operation is *not* thread safe.

Comment: In this sense we can talk about very wide range of things. But generally I would agree with your point.

Comment: @JohnBollinger added your hint in my answer

Comment: Just to clarify:  it is safe if the source collection is *guarded* by synchronization or a lock, but it is not guaranteed to be safe if the collection was created by [Collections.synchronizedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) or [Collections.synchronizedCollection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection-java.util.Collection-).  Those methods only synchronize access to individual elements.

Comment: @VGR This is obviously not true. `Collections.synchronizedList` or `Collections.synchronizedCollection` return SynchronizedCollection instance (or subclass of it), where `toArray()` is synchronized as other methods

Comment: I see nothing in the [ArrayList constructor’s contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) that guarantees it will use `toArray` internally.  Any future version of Java is free to use a different implementation, and it is the developer who relied on the current implementation who will be at fault when synchronization fails in that case, not Java.

Comment: Did you read my answer carefully? I've mentioned that I'm talking about particular implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your specific question is the answer to the question - is the source collection thread safe?

The best way to go about trying to understand how we get there, we can go to the source.

Starting with [ArrayList](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l168)

```
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    elementData = c.toArray();
        size = elementData.length;
        // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
        if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
            elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
    }
```

Diving into the documentation for [Collection.toArray](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collection.java#l191)

```
/**
 * Returns an array containing all of the elements in this collection.
 * If this collection makes any guarantees as to what order its elements
 * are returned by its iterator, this method must return the elements in
 * the same order.
 *
 * <p>The returned array will be "safe" in that no references to it are
 * maintained by this collection.  (In other words, this method must
 * allocate a new array even if this collection is backed by an array).
 * The caller is thus free to modify the returned array.
 *
 * <p>This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based
 * APIs.
 *
 * @return an array containing all of the elements in this collection
 */
Object[] toArray();
```

Back to [ArrayList.toArray](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l346) (Assuming the source collections runtime type is an ArrayList)

```
/**
 * Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list
 * in proper sequence (from first to last element).
 *
 * <p>The returned array will be "safe" in that no references to it are
 * maintained by this list.  (In other words, this method must allocate
 * a new array).  The caller is thus free to modify the returned array.
 *
 * <p>This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based
 * APIs.
 *
 * @return an array containing all of the elements in this list in
 *         proper sequence
 */
public Object[] toArray() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
}
```

and finally onto [Array.copyOf](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l3178)

```
/**
 * Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with nulls (if necessary)
 * so the copy has the specified length.  For all indices that are
 * valid in both the original array and the copy, the two arrays will
 * contain identical values.  For any indices that are valid in the
 * copy but not the original, the copy will contain <tt>null</tt>.
 * Such indices will exist if and only if the specified length
 * is greater than that of the original array.
 * The resulting array is of the class <tt>newType</tt>.
 *
 * @param <U> the class of the objects in the original array
 * @param <T> the class of the objects in the returned array
 * @param original the array to be copied
 * @param newLength the length of the copy to be returned
 * @param newType the class of the copy to be returned
 * @return a copy of the original array, truncated or padded with nulls
 *     to obtain the specified length
 * @throws NegativeArraySizeException if <tt>newLength</tt> is negative
 * @throws NullPointerException if <tt>original</tt> is null
 * @throws ArrayStoreException if an element copied from
 *     <tt>original</tt> is not of a runtime type that can be stored in
 *     an array of class <tt>newType</tt>
 * @since 1.6
 */
public static <T,U> T[] copyOf(U[] original, int newLength, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] copy = ((Object)newType == (Object)Object[].class)
        ? (T[]) new Object[newLength]
        : (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

System.arraycopy is a native method. The call to `c.toArray` at the top of its invocation stack uses `System.arraycopy` which is a native method which isn't documented to be thread safe.

Moving back down the stack, the answer to your specific question is the answer to the question - is the source collection thread safe?

If you are using an ArrayList as the source collection, you will need to ensure thread safety in your code.

Comment: Going to the source can be helpful to *clarify and interpret* the documentation, but it is rarely wise to rely on anything you find there in any other way.  If it's undocumented then it can change without warning.  That's perhaps an acceptable risk if such a change is something you're sure to notice quickly, but in no way could I justify a risk that my code's thread safety is lost as a result of such a change.

Comment: It is wiser to rely on code than to rely on documentation. In this instance if you rely on code and notice that it isn't adequately synchronized you code for that and if/when it were reimplemented to be thread safe you lose nothing. 
You are making a leap from my suggestion to read to code making a recommendation, I'm not doing that.

Comment: I'm sorry, but just no.  Observations of details of a particular implementation, including its code, tells you only about that implementation.  It is not only foolish but unsafe to rely on such observations to answer questions that are any more general than that, such as the OP's.  API documentation, on the other hand, defines the behavior expected of *every* correct implementation.  Relying on documentation instead of implementation is one realization of the good practice of programming to interfaces.

Comment: As I said previously, you are making a leap from my suggestion to read code to making a recommendation on the decision. My response starts with the only right answer `is the source collection thread safe`. My only comment to your response is - whatever floats your boat.

Comment: "Is the source collection thread safe" is neither a necessary nor a sufficient condition for the OP's proposed operation to be thread-safe.  It is not necessary because the `ArrayList` constructor could provide the needed synchronization itself (though it does not in fact do so).  It is not sufficient because the `ArrayList` constructor could use methods of the original collection that are *individually* thread safe and yet produce a result that does not satisfy the OP's conditions.  For example, it might obtain the collection's elements via its `Iterator`.